# Librato > Composite Metrics: Subtract two meters

Tags: metrics, librato

I have two different meters reporting values:

Meter A: Items looked up against data store
Meter B: Items returned from data store

I want my chart to also have a composite metric that just tracks the difference between these two values for easy observation. However, I'm struggling getting Librato to report this value properly.

What I have at this point is based on the `subtract` example here: http://support.metrics.librato.com/knowledgebase/articles/354670-composite-metrics-language-tutorial

However, the results it reports are a scale factor off of the real number. It seems the number it reports is the actual number divided by some number, which may be the number of separate  sources reporting the value.

For instance
Metric A = 100 items
Metrics B = 50 items
Composite = 25 items ?? (seems to be off by factor of 2)

The factor changes depending on the specific datapoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rich,

Without seeing the actual data streams I'm just taking a guess, but there are a couple of possibilities:

- Picking a summary function: If the metric is reporting multiple client-side aggregated samples, it may be reporting as a complex gauge with individual components of: count, sum, min, max, etc. To view the total number of items in the metric you would want to choose the *sum* property. You can do this by setting `"function":sum` as an option to the `series` function.
- Aligning data points in time: The `subtract` function works by subtracting points aligned in time. If the two metrics are reporting at different time steps there may be points where they don't align. You can fix this by setting a `measure_time` when POSTing the samples to the API or by setting the `period` option of the `series` function to the period of the data.

Always feel free to copy us at support@librato.com on any questions.

Comment: The solution was adding `"function": sum` to the options for the sums on the complex gauges. Jason Derrett was able to help me over e-mail just to give him credit